# NG Lint Show Progress

Tags: angular-cli, eslint, eslintrc

When running

```
eslint --debug <file>
```

I get a whole chunk of debug coming out, regarding what it is doing next. For example:

```
  eslint:source-code-fixer No fixes to apply +0ms
  eslint:file-enumerator Complete iterating files: ["src/app/core/core.module.ts"] +931ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting complete in: 932ms +34ms
  eslint:cli Fix mode enabled - applying fixes +949ms
```

How do I get the same output using ng lint? I need to debug why things are being so slow. I don't see any immediate option to do this, is it configuration to be added somewhere?